# operations with dates firefox vs chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Why this subtract works fine with chrome but not with firefox:

```
if(((new Date()) - (new Date(res.last_connection)))/(1000*60)<12) //12 minits
```

res.last_connection is a date on SQL format, the javascript request to the server, it makes a query to the DB, and directly return the result, that is something like: "2015-10-28 23:13:35".

The next solution I thought wasthis:

```
if(((new Date()).getTime() - (new Date(res.last_connection.replace(" ", "T"))).getTime())/(1000*60)<12)
```

The replace of the blank space works on firefox but not on chrome. The new problem (with chrome) is that the time is one hour ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

After a long time typing the question and making some test (I even made an account on), I think that I found the solution:

```
 if(((new Date()).getTime() - (new Date(res.last_connection.replace(/-/g,"/"))).getTime())/(1000*60)<12)
```

Replacing the scripts for slashes seems that works!! :D

Thank you.

Comment: The account is on jsfiddle :)